# Spring/TestNG integration: Auto-injection fails with two test classes

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, testng

Hitting an odd issue with my spring based integration tests.  Note that I'm not so much unit testing a spring IoC app as I'm using Spring to auto-inject properties into my test configuration.  **Also** - we're not using any context configuration xml, everything is configured programatically.

I got the framework all set up and running with a single test before handing it off to the team tester, auto-injection was working fine.  However, as soon as he added a second test class, auto-injection of my configuration field just stops working.  I've cloned his branch and verified the behavior; Commenting out his class OR my original class causes the auto-injection to return to normal function.

Anybody ever seen this?  Relevant code snippets below.  I've tried moving around the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation but it didn't really help.  It seems like Spring is having trouble deciding where the TestProperties object should come from. The field I've commented on below is coming up null when I run the tests, but only if there are two test classes enabled.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public abstract class BaseIntegrationTest
        extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
    @Autowired
    protected MockServerClient mockServer;

    // I get an error in IntelliJ Pro on this field.  
    // Could not autowire.  There is more than one bean of 'TestProperties' type. Beans: getTestProperties, testProperties
    // I've also tried     @Qualifier("getTestProperties") and @Qualifier("testProperties")
    // which both resolve the error in IntelliJ but the TestProperties field is still null when running the tests.
    @Autowired
    protected TestProperties properties; 

    //...
}

public class TestGetMuIT
        extends BaseIntegrationTest
{
    private ManagementUnitClient managementUnitClient;

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup()
    {
        String endpoint = properties.getServiceBaseUri(); //NullPointerException thrown here during test run
    }
}
```

Other relevant classes:

```
@Configuration
public class RootConfig
{

    protected static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RootConfig.class);

    private PropertyService propertyService;
    private TestProperties testProperties;

    @Bean
    public PropertyService propertyService() throws IOException {
        if (propertyService == null) {
            propertyService = new DynamoDbPropertyService(config.getPropertiesConfig());
            propertyService.initialize();
        }

        return propertyService;
    }

    @Bean
    public TestProperties getTestProperties() throws IOException {

        if (testProperties == null) {
            testProperties = new TestProperties();
        }
}
```

And the actual TestProperties class:

```
@Component
public class TestProperties
{
    public static class Default {
        public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8055";
    }

    @Autowired
    private PropertyService propertyService;

    public String getServiceBaseUri()
    {
        return propertyService.getPropertyRegistry().getString(TestConfigKey.LocalServiceBaseUri.key(), Default.BASE_URI);
    }
}
```

And these are my spring config annotations:

```
@Configuration 
//Note: TestProperties.class is a recent addition.  I added that and commented out the @Bean getTestProperties() method in RootConfig as a troubleshooting step
@Import({RootConfig.class, TestProperties.class})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.inin.wfm.it"},
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = com.inin.wfm.it.config.ConfigPackageExcludeFilter.class, type = FilterType.CUSTOM))
public class TestConfig {\\... }
```

Again all of the above works just fine if there's only one test file (and it doesn't matter which of the two I comment out).  Anybody know what I'm doing wrong in my configuration?